# Materialize Dropdown not Working in Handlebars Rendering

Tags: jquery, materialize, express-handlebars

Other posts on this issue haven't helped me out so far, so I thought I'd share my challenge.

This below is my `main.handlebars` setup including my jQuery and Materialize libraries, as well as an explicit  section to initialize the `dropdown()` method.

```
<body>
  {{{body}}}
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
      alert("jquery load");
      debugger;
      $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
    });
  </script>

</body>
```

And rendering within that `{{body}}`, here is the part of my nav that has the desired drop-down:

```
    <a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

    <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
    <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content' role="menu">
      <li><a href="#city">City</a></li>
      <li><a href="#host">Host</a></li>
      <li><a href="#interest">Interest</a></li>
      <li><a href="#dates"><i class="material-icons">view_module</i>Dates</a></li>
      <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
      <li><a href="#all"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>All</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Based on what I've read I should be all good . . . and I know that the initialize `<script>` runs by testing with an `alert()`, but get no action.  Stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using Materialize version 0.100.2, but you are reading the documentation for Materialize version 1.0.0.

If you want to use version 0.1, you will need to use the attribute `data-activates` instead of `data-target` and the class name `dropdown-button` instead of `dropdown-trigger` in your markup.

More information on breaking changes between two version can be found here: https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v1-dev/v1-upgrade-guide.md

Cheers!

Comment: A-ha! Thank you friend, I am glad this was so simple! Thank you for your good eye, I very much appreciate it!